# List recent operations on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with Node.js framework.

There is a weird behavior that some documents are not getting inserted into db, though from orm's point of view there are no errors: `err = null` in callback of `Collection.create()` and fresh document with `_id` is returned. When I try to search by that `_id` in db - no document is found.

I tried to manually insert new document to db and it was successfull.

Is there a way I can trace these operations from db's point of view? Some command to list recent requests and their results..?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable profiling for all operations:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

Then, look at `system.profile` collection to see what's happen.  `system.profile` is a capped collection that can be searched as any other collection. Profiling can be noisy, and eventually you should have to change the size of the `system.profile` collection

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0)

db.system.profile.drop()

db.createCollection( "system.profile", { capped: true, size:4000000 } )

db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

Comment: Note currently this will create a lot of noise, a query will need to be used to filter out the OPs the OP is looking for and the capped collection for system.profile may need to be resized depending upon the length of the capture

Answer (score 0):

The most notable way of tracking errors within MongoDB is to use the `--diaglog` option: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--diaglog with maybe a level of `3`, however `1` might be enough for you.

As noted by @Neil this has unfortunately become deprecated as of 2.6.

The only way currently is to write out ALL operations MongoDB performs, via @Rauls answer, and then use a query like:

```
db.system.profile.find({op:{$in:['update', 'insert', 'remove']}});
```

and possibly resize the capped collection used for profiling: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#profiler-overhead to capture the amount you want.

Comment: The --diaglog option is considered [deprecated](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#diaglog-option-for-mongod-deprecated) as of development release 2.5.5 and will be removed in future versions. So not a good option to recommend it's usage.

Comment: @NeilLunn too bad it produces better stats than profiling level alone

Comment: Profiling is the preferred option and slated for improvements.

Comment: @NeilLunn well its going need quite a few improvements, but fair enough